# Databinding doesn't seem to work on a specific part

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I was trying to make a webstore for a school project.
The problem is that near the bottom i want to get the selected name into the textbox, but it just doesn't seem to work

```
     <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Default="clr-namespace" x:Class="Project.BrowseStore"
    Title="Browse the store" Height="501.786" Width="735.714" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107.94,65.044,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CmbSort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270.627,65.044,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" ToolTip="Sorteren" Tag="Sorteren" Text="Sorteren">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Alle" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Alle"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Prijs groter dan" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Prijs"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Prijs kleiner dan" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Prijs"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Naam" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Naam"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Boeken" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Alle"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Games" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Alle"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jaaruitgave" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_Jaaruitgave"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <Label Content="Zoeken op" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122.94,65.044,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82.77" Height="25.96"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtSort" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="427.344,65.044,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.062,0.519"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnGo" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="581.075,67.044,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="143.761,117.284,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&#xA;" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Order" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130.71,442.226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <DockPanel x:Name="Panel" Height="282.226" LastChildFill="False" Margin="23.493,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="683.881">
        <ListView x:Name="lstSort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="138.209" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="683.881" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Naam"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Naam}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Prijs" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Prijs}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Jaaruitgave" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Jaaruitgave}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Afbeelding" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Afbeelding}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Uitgever" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Uitgever}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stock" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Stock}"/>



                </GridView>

            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
        <TextBox Height="144.017" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Naam}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

This part just doesnt seem to work...

```
     <TextBox Height="144.017" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Naam}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because your DataContext is not set for that TextBox element. The GridView works because you set (in code I guess) DataContext/Source to some list of values. You could Bind currently selected item from GridView and then Bind that value to the TextBox. Comment if you need code example...

Comment: An example would be nice. Still new to databinding... It's still really confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example using [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). Take a look at it. Once you understand how it works, you'll ask yourself how did you do anything at all without it :D

This is how you should modify your window (XAML) class

```
<Window ... DataContext="ViewModel">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BrowseStoreViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
    <DockPanel ...>
        ...
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Naam}" ... />
    </DockPanel>
```

Now you should create an ViewModel for that window, we'll name it `BrowseStoreViewModel`

```
public class BrowseStoreViewModel : DependencyObject {
    // Dependency property for Selected Item
    // Replace "ItemType" with type you're populating GridView
    public ItemType SelectedItem {
        get { return (ItemType )GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(ItemType), typeof(BrowseStoreViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(ItemType)));
}
```

Now just set ViewModel.SelectedItem to currently selected item (on selection change) and TextBox should update automatically. I don't exactly know how to direcly bind selected row to ViewModel.SelectedItem but it should look something like this:

```
<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"> ...
```

Comment: Tyvm! this helped a lot :)